# How to apply css hover style to a child element that has been given it's own style

Tags: css

I have a button div which contains two child div elements. One with a `count` class, and one with a `caption` class.

If I **don't** set a color for the `.count` class, then the button hover style (white) will apply to the count div. However, if I set a color in the `.count` class, then the button hover, no longer applies to the count class/div. I can define a hover style for the count div, however it will only apply when the cursor moves over the count, not the button as a whole. How can I set a specific color for the count class, but still have it's color change (to button hover color) when hover over the button?

Sample Code:

```css
.button {
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.button .count {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: green;
}

.button:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: gray;
}

.button .count:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button">
    <div class="count">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
      Videos
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sample demo:
https://codepen.io/raelb/pen/OJWrpKw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a second selector targetting the child element in your `.button:hover` rule:

```css
.button {
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.button .count {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: green;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

.button:hover,
.button:hover .count {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button">
    <div class="count">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
      Videos
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There's nothing forcing you to end your selector with `:hover`.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing a css priority issue :)

The colour property defined inside the count class has a higher priority than the one you declare in the hover pseudo-class of your button.

A way to solve that would be to use:

```
.button:hover count { color: white; }
```